# when trying to build sikuli from source on windows 8 64-bit using Visual Studio 2012 for windows desktop, cmake raising following issues

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, cmake, tesseract, sikuli

I'm trying to build sikuli from source after so that I could edit sikuli source in future and generate my own executable. I installed the necessary softwares and followed instructions as given here in the below link:

https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli/blob/develop/build-win32.txt

I end up with the following errors:

```
Tesseract-OCR Data Path: c:/tesseract-2.04/tessdata
Tesseract-OCR Data Path: c:/tesseract-2.04/tessdata
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
CMake Warning (dev) at c:/OpenCV2.1/OpenCVConfig.cmake:39 (LINK_DIRECTORIES):
  This command specifies the relative path



  as a link directory.

  Policy CMP0015 is not set: link_directories() treats paths relative to the
  source dir.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0015" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  E:/tsn/sikuli/cmake_modules/FindOpenCV.cmake:77 (include)
  src/main/native/CMakeLists.txt:26 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

found OpenCVConfig c:/OpenCV2.1/include;c:/OpenCV2.1/include/opencv
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPack
ageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (message):
  Could NOT find SWIG (missing: SWIG_EXECUTABLE SWIG_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStan
dardArgs.cmake:291 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindSWIG.cmake:67 (FI
ND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/main/native/CMakeLists.txt:28 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

PS: I'm using Windows 8 (64 bit), Visual Studio 2012 for windows desktop (installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0) and its command prompt, opencv 2.4, tesseract 2.04 + english data, SWIG, jdk 6 and cmake 2.8 to build the executable. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you try running `cmake . -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=<path to SWIG executable on your machine>`

Comment: it gives me another error

Comment: `E:\tsn\sikuli\sikuli-script\build>cmake . -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=E:\tsn\swigwin-2.0.9
\swig.exe
Tesseract-OCR Data Path: C:/tesseract-2.04/tessdata
Tesseract-OCR Data Path: C:/tesseract-2.04/tessdata
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
CMake Error at E:/tsn/sikuli/cmake_modules/FindOpenCV.cmake:154 (message):
  OpenCV required but some headers or libs not found.  Please specify OpenCV
  directory using OpenCV_DIR env.  variable
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/main/native/CMakeLists.txt:26 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`

Comment: Looks like it's now not finding OpenCV (where it did before!).  Try `cmake . -DOpenCV_DIR=<path to OpenCV root on your machine>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the paths of jdk 1.6 and swig to system environment variables and everything goes fine

```
jdk path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin;

swig path: C:\swigwin-2.0.9;
```